# Output forfiles error to a variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, output

I am trying to save the output of forfiles to a variable in batch.

I've tried a few things to set a var to the output directly  as well as saving to a file

Long story short, I am comparing the output text to another string variable, if it matches an event log is created and I get an alert.

Everything in my script works as intended other than saving the forfile output to the variable so I can compare it to my default text variable

forfiles /P %filename% /D -1 > variable
set TEST=

the variable just stays completely blank.

If I run the command just in command prompt it outputs like this

forfiles /P C:\users\justin.pcs\desktop\test\ /D -1 > variable
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.

So I am getting the error I am watching for, but the variable stays blank. I'm assuming I am missing some sort of switch that is necessary for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the output of a command, either redirect STDERR to a file and read it back:

```
forfiles /P C:\users\justin.pcs\desktop\test\ /D -1  2>temp
<temp set /p variable=
echo %variable"%
```

or use a `for` construct (no temporary file needed):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('forfiles /P C:\users\justin.pcs\desktop\test\ /D -1  2^>^&1 1^>nul') do set variable=%%a
echo %variable%
```

The redirections (`2^>^&1 1^>nul`)are needed, because STDOUT is parsed, but you need STDERR.